# trying to use ‘connect’ to get value from template reducer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- i am new to react.
- i am trying to use ‘connect’ to get value from template reducer
- i am facing the below error
  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined**
- can you tell me how to fix it
- providing the whole code in fiddle
  https://jsfiddle.net/bmfzLs3z/1/
- providing the snippet code below

  import React from 'react';
      import {connect} from 'react-redux';
      import {dateValue} from '../../common/mixin-money-format';
      import time from 'time';
      import '../../../css/SPORTS-tracker-tile.css';

  ```
  export default React.createClass({
      propTypes: {
          value: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
          profile: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  ```

Comment: You're not passing a component to the function that connect returns.. did you read this? http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html, also you should definitely include the code for the component in your question.

Comment: @azium thanks for your reply...i have included the code in the fiddle...can you update my code.... it is so confusing :(

Comment: Well no, I'm not going to do that... maybe you should start with a smaller example? Where are you learning from?

Comment: @azium I went through the documentation but still not able to find it

Comment: `connect` returns a function, which you are supposed to pass a component to. You are calling it without a component, so the props you are mapping from state are going nowhere. Re-read the section on Container Components.

Comment: @azium I updated the code but I am getting another error...any idea about it----------> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReservationCard is not defined